# Fitting an exponential model to data

Tags: r

I have 2 variables, both from class "numeric":

`> head(y)

[1] 0.4651804 0.6185849 0.3766175 0.5489810 0.3695258 0.4002567`
`> head(x)

[1]  59.32820  68.46436  80.76974 132.90824 216.75995 153.25551`

I plotted them, and now I would like to fit an exponential model to the data (and add it to the plot) but I cannot find any info on fitting models to multivariate data in R! Only to univariate data, can somebody help? I don't even know where to start... Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  You say you have two "independent" variables (I prefer "predictor", but that's not important).  Do you have any "dependent"/"response" variables?  If these were both response variables, I can imagine fitting a parametric, bivariate probability distribution (with or without predictor variables on which the distribution's parameters depended) -- or a 2D kernel density estimate.  Perhaps you could explain the context a bit more. (PS whoever's upvoting the question must know what it means ... anyone care to chime in?)

Comment: In any case, you'd better go to http://www.crossvalidated.com for such questions. or to an obscure website called Google. It did find information on fitting models to multivariate data. Quite a lot (4 million two hundred and thirty thousand to be exact)

Comment: I'd recommend bing - it is a decision engine after all, search engines are so 20th century...just look at Yahoo and Ask Jeeves, how irrelevant are they today?!?

Comment: @Ben Bolker - Thanks for helping, I have taken the independent out, cause it was not correct. What I have is distance between locations (x) and correlations of rainfall between locations (y)

Comment: note that you will have to use special methods if you want to make statistical inferences on these data, because if the distances were computed on a common set of locations, they are not independent -- search e.g. for "Mantel test"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you're asking, because your lingo is off. But assuming that your variables aren't independent *of one another* (if they were, then they're be no relation to find) I'll give it a try. If `x` is your independent (or predictor) variable and `y` is your dependent (or response) variable, then this should work.

```
# generate data
beta <- 0.05
n <- 100
temp <- data.frame(y = exp(beta * seq(n)) + rnorm(n), x = seq(n))

# plot data
plot(temp$x, temp$y)

# fit non-linear model
mod <- nls(y ~ exp(a + b * x), data = temp, start = list(a = 0, b = 0))

# add fitted curve
lines(temp$x, predict(mod, list(x = temp$x)))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have taken the word "independent" out, as you pointed out, it didn't make sense. Using your code for my data I can fit the model but the result is dozens of lines in the graph instead of just one. Any idea why?

Comment: @sbg -- No, sorry, I can't think of a reason why. Does `nls()` fit a model?

Comment: I think so, I get: Nonlinear regression model
  model:  y ~ exp(a + b * x) 
   data:  DF 
        a         b 
-0.535834 -0.002024 
 residual sum-of-squares: 18.62

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.08e-06

Comment: @sbg try sorting your `x` variable: `lines(sort(temp$x),predict(mod, list(x=sort(temp$x)))`