# Fitting a model in R

Tags: r, regression, model, fitting

How do I fit a model of the form $y = a + b \exp(−cx)$ to my data in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting an exponential model to data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/fitting-an-exponential-model-to-data)